# How to get VM's usage pattern?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

We are having VMware ESXi servers. VMs will be assigned to user and they will use RDP to use it. We are unable to find whether the users are really using them or the VMs are idle.

Is there any way to find it?

Answer (score 2):

Check the "Performance" tab for each VM in your vSphere Client.

Also, in your vCenter Server settings, make sure you set appropriate retention periods for logs, events, and performance data.

Comment: Dude i am having 12 ESXi servers. Looking into each VM performance data is nearly impossible task. Is there any way to do this using VMware powercli or some other mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to tell if the users are using it - have the Windows server log its RDP connection stats to a file (CSV, ODBC, SQL, etc) and have a look at it in there. Alternately, most monitoring solutions (Nagios, zabbix, etc) can pull this info out through their agents too.

You don't mention which version of Windows you will be installing, so I'm going to assume Server 2008 R2, in which case the `perfmon` counter you want to log is `Terminal Services\Active Sessions` (yes, even though it's now called RDS, the logging is still underter Terminal Services)

[image]

Comment: Would this not show them as active isf the user disconnected instead of logging out? Because he went home?

Comment: I wants to know whether it is idle. As Tom says , it may show even if it is disconnected ,isn't it?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu - no, active sessions are only sessions that are actually active. Once the session passes the idle timeout (which is by default, never, so you will need to configure it), it moves into "inactive" sessions. If they logg off, it dissapears from the counters alltogether. The catch with monitoring from VMWare is that it shows disk access, processor usage and RAM utilisation. A machine can be in use and have all those things virtually idle.

Comment: Not all the machines are W2k8 R2. W2k8 Sp , Windows 7 and W2ka8 R2 are the majority of the machines

Comment: @Samselvaprabu - Windows Server since 2003 has the counter, as does XP Professional and Windows 7 Professional/Ultimate/Enterprise, so basically any version of Windows form the last 10 years.